# How to embed a Twitter Timeline filtered by a hash tag

Tags: twitter

I am trying to create a twitter timeline which includes tweets related to a specific hashtag.

Then I need to embed it to a website.

I tried https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/ but it informs me to go  https://publish.twitter.com/

But it doesn't provide support to do the embed.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [no support for embedded search timelines](https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecating-widget-settings/102295) any more (as of July 2018). You'll need to build something that searches the API for the Tweets you want to include, and then use the `oembed` API to display the Tweets in your webpage.